# Travis CI - bypass 50m timeout for Haskell Stack builds

Tags: haskell, travis-ci, haskell-stack

I have a Haskell project with 300+ files (mostly auto generated). I can build it in few minutes with my 4 yo. processor (by specifying ghc-options: $everything: -j in stack.yaml) but when it comes to Travis things becomes really slow. It seems that modules being processed sequentially and even single module compilation time much larger (about one second on my machine vs tens on seconds on Travis) Eventually I hit Travis timeout (50 min for single job). Is there any way to speed up Travis build or to split up compilation process to multiple jobs? I would accept paid plan from Travis, I need solution which just works without complex setup.

Comment: I’m going to assume your local builds are caching  artifacts, while Travis is not.  That would be the first thing I would look into.

Comment: I've measured it with clean build, it took less than 3 minutes. As for external artifact (ghc itself and other libraries) - Travis managed to cache them as well.

Comment: Oh, that's really weird then.  Is the build log on Travis showing you that it's compiling things you are not locally?

Comment: No, it compiles only project files. But this takes to long and compilation timed out. Long compilation time itself quite explainable: I use 4 core 4GHz processor to compile locally, Travis likely allocates 1 core server grade processor with much lower frequency. So 10x time difference does not looks weird to me. The question is how to deal with it. Starting Travis Enterprise seems to be overkill.

Answer (score 0):

This configuration uses stages: https://github.com/google/codeworld/blob/f20020ca78fee51afdf6a5ef13eacc6d15c15724/.travis.yml

However, there are unpredictable problems with the cache, or perhaps problems with the Travis config: https://travis-ci.org/google/codeworld/builds/626216910  Also, I am not sure how Travis utilizes the cache(s) for simultaneous builds.

https://github.com/google/codeworld/blob/f20020ca78fee51afdf6a5ef13eacc6d15c15724/.travis.yml#L52-L63 , https://github.com/google/codeworld/blob/f20020ca78fee51afdf6a5ef13eacc6d15c15724/.travis.yml#L74 , and the redundant calls to `stack upgrade --binary-only` are attempts to work around these issues.